# Android: Recycler view is not scrolling to last position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, window-soft-input-mode

I am trying to create a chat screen by using the Recycler view. Because of chat when ever user enter to the screen the list should scroll to last position.

**My problem is when keyboard open the list is hiding**.
If we use adjust pan, entire view is going to up, I trying to scroll only the list, I want title bar remain same position when the keyboard open

Comment: Have you tried using adjust resize instead??

Comment: please paste your `xml` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your code and check....It works fine for me....

```
mRecyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) 
    {
        if (mRecyclerAdapter != null) 
        {
            if (bottom < oldBottom) 
            {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Add this line to when you get new message....

```
mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
```

Comment: its working, but when i sending the message, the list scroll below to 3 lines

Answer (score 0):

No need to add android:windowSoftInputMode in the manifest. Just keep your recycler view above the bottom view. Hope this will be helpful.`

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </RelativeLayout>
             <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlBottom"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/dimen_8"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_write_msg"
                android:elevation="@dimen/dimen_2">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_12"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_12"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ivAdd"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ivSend"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:hint="@string/label_type_here"
                    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/sp_12"
                    android:visibility="visible" />


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivSend"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_4"
                    android:padding="@dimen/dimen_8"
                    android:src="@drawable/drawable_send"
                    android:visibility="visible" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`